# What is the unit for durations on the AAVSO website?

Tags: variable-star

The [AAVSO website](https://www.aavso.org/aavso-binocular-program) has a page for observers with binoculars. On this page, there is a table with stars of interest, and the period of each variable is indicated. However, the unit for the period is not.

First line of the table:

> Name  N/S     AUID    Coords  Const   Type    Period  Mag     Min FOV/ Lim Mag
>
> EG  And   North   000-BBC-010     00 44 37.19     And     ZAND+E  482.57  6.97 - 7.8 V    180 arcmin/ 9.5

So EG And has a period of 482.57. But what is the unit for the period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a few stars that I recognize (omicron Ceti, R Aqr) the period is in units of days. The period for these types of stars is often on the order of one year.

The precision is misleading. I assume the high "precision" is based on the number of days divided by multiple cycles; in other words, it is a long term average. The period for individual cycles will vary.